# create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) error in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a custom user model for my API. The following are the codes for my project:

**models.py**

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        account.is_staff = True
        account.is_superuser = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser
```

I am serializing the Account model using a serializer as shown below in **serializers.py**

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'confirm_password',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)

        instance.save()

        password = validated_data.get('password', None)
        confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

        if password and confirm_password and password == confirm_password:
            instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()

        return instance
```

And of course I have a view-set which handles the API requests through an end-point, **views.py**

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I try to post a new user through the API, I get this error:

`create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) error`

I also have this as my traceback:

http://dpaste.com/2ED1XSX

So what exactly am I doing wrong? I basically followed a tutorial to do this. Any help? Thanks a lot.

**Edit**

I fixed the indentation error, but I still get the same error :/

Comment: It's been a long time since I even touched `rest-framework` so I'm just guessing here: I think your `AccountViewSet` 's `create` method needs to take the `request` as a parameter.

Comment: Nope, still same error. Thanks though.

Comment: Checked [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py) and [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) and it seems that  create does need a second parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong, `create()` and `update()` methods should be defined on the "serializer" level - not on the `Meta` class level:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)

        instance.save()

        password = validated_data.get('password', None)
        confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

        if password and confirm_password and password == confirm_password:
            instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'confirm_password',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)
```

Note that in the code above, I've also moved them before the `Meta` inner class definition - this usually helps to avoid problems like this one.

Comment: Very good suggestion about moving the function definitions before meta.

Comment: I fixed this embarrassing mistake, but I still get the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee hm, have you restarted the development server?

Comment: Yes of course, restarted my virtual environment, and cleared all my cookies as well.